# Push data directly from Filebeats to AWS ES managed service

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, filebeat

My issue is that I am trying to stream data from Filebeat to AWS ElasticSearch.

I approached this by providing the AWS endpoint in the beats output entry.

I tried both port 80 and 443 to no avail.

I checked [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/sending-filebeat-data-to-aws-elasticsearch-service-endpoint/41974/7) post, and from this I suppose that it is possible to push directly to AWSbut still cannot figure out how.

It would be really helpful if any of you has been through this and could shed some light!

Thank you!

Comment: could you do manual curl on any other http request on AWS elastic?

Comment: Yes I can @Mysterion

Comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filebeats-to-ship-data-directly-to-aws-elasticsearch-managed-service/163988

From elastic forum they tell me that aws cannot provide basic auth over https => filebeat cannot communicate directly with aws. 

For logstash there is a plugin which works fine, but doesn't support filebeats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with permissions.

Make sure that the logs filebeat is trying to stream have the same permission as the *filebeat.yml*.

You can simply issue a *chmod 777* to both files.

Finally, make sure, to prepend *:443* after AWS ES endpoint.

Comment: Hi Kejsi, I am trying to push logs from FileBeat to OpenSearch [Not AWS OpenSearch]. What I want is : I want to push all logs in some  Index created in OpenSearch. How do I configure this at runtime that in which index these logs should get stored in OpenSearch? So that, I can search logs based on index name.

Answer (score 0):

I was using 7.10 version of Filebeat and Logstash.

> [Below blog](https://learningsubway.com/category/elasticsearch/)

help me lot.

Steps are as:

```
Open filebeat.yml in any editor of your choice from location

/etc/filebeat/ on Linux or

C:\Program Files\filebeat-7.10.0 on windows

filebeat:
inputs:
– paths:
– E:/nginx-1.20.1/logs/.log
input_type: log


filebeat.config.modules:
enabled: true
path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml


output:
logstash:
hosts: [“localhost:5044”]

Logstash Configuration

input {
beats {
port => 5044
ssl => false
}
}

filter {
grok {
match => [ “message” , “%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}+%{GREEDYDATA:extra_fields}”]
overwrite => [ “message” ]
}
mutate {
convert => [“response”, “integer”]
convert => [“bytes”, “integer”]
convert => [“responsetime”, “float”]
}
geoip {
source => “clientip”
target => “geoip”
add_tag => [ “nginx-geoip” ]
}
date {
match => [ “timestamp” , “dd/MMM/YYYY:HH:mm:ss Z” ]
remove_field => [ “timestamp” ]
}
useragent {
source => “agent”
}
}

output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => [“https://arun-learningsubway-ybalglooophuhyjmik3zmkmiq4.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com:443”]
index => “arun_nginx”
document_type => “%{[@metadata][type]}”
user => “myusername”
password => “mypassword”
manage_template => false
template_overwrite => false
ilm_enabled => false
}
}
```